# Android Studio Program Crash

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-studio

I have two activities Main, and Game_Activity 
When my app launches and I click a button to take me to the Game_Activity it crashes...
Main

@Override

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnHelp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHelp);
    Button btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    Button btnSettings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSettings);
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GameActivity.class); //gets us to Game activity when Start Button is clicked
        startActivity(i);
        overridePendingTransition(R.animator.animation1, R.animator.animation2);
        }
    });
}
```

Game_Activity

```
ViewGroup kamilsLayout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    kamilsLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.kamilsLayout);


    Button kamilsButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kamilsButton2);
    kamilsButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            moveButton();
        }
    });
}

public void moveButton(){
    View kamilsButton = findViewById(R.id.kamilsButton);

    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(kamilsLayout);
    //Change size of the button
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams sizeRules = kamilsButton.getLayoutParams();
    sizeRules.height = 700;

    kamilsButton.setLayoutParams(sizeRules);
}
```

Here is Logcat sorry for last lines but couldn't format it... :/

```
03-02 21:32:49.073  22427-22427/com.example.kamil.mychemicalreaction E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.kamil.mychemicalreaction, PID: 22427
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kamil.mychemicalreaction/com.example.kamil.mychemicalreaction.GameActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.kamil.mychemicalreaction.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.java:25)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:126)at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

XML 
Game_Activity

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:id="@+id/kamilsButton"
    android:gravity="bottom|fill_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#ff6aff01" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Click"
    android:id="@+id/kamilsButton2"
    android:textSize="9dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="102dp" />
```

Menu

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="My Chemical Reaction"
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ffa946ff"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnStart"
    android:text="Start"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    android:layout_marginBottom="61dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnSettings"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnSettings"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnSettings" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSettings"
    android:text="Settings"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnHelp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="58dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnHelp"
    android:text="Help"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnSettings"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnSettings"
    android:layout_marginBottom="81dp" />
```

Comment: Post your xml too please

Comment: Whats on line 25 of GameActivity?

Comment: Looks like there's no view with the id kamilsLayout

Comment: No the java file, thats where it crashes

Comment: kamilsButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                moveButton();
            }
        });

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a NullPointerException when trying to reference your UI elements. From your XML, it appears you haven't given any layout an id of `kamilsLayout`. Try enclosing your UI elements in a layout with this ID.

Comment: Don't know why this didn't show up at the start.

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.kamil.mychemicalreaction.GameActivity"
    android:id="@+id/kamilsLayout">

Comment: What is the name of XML files you are using for `MainActiviy` and `GameActivity`?

Comment: activity_main and activity_game

Answer (score 0):

Like Josef said. You're setting the same XML for two both activities, is that expected? 
You're using `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`. Maybe there is no `ViewGroup` on `R.layout.activity_main layout`. And you're trying to setting up that `

> kamilsLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.kamilsLayout);

`